# Linux / bash write to new file if csv value is satisfied

Tags: linux, bash

I have a CSV file containing the following:

```
Name,Price,Date,SKU
```

I the date is formatted `yyy-mm-dd` and I want to take all items in the file from `2020-01` and put them in their own file in a different directory.

The results file will not exist at first but I need to run this on 3 csv files so it will exist for the last 2 runs. I want to maintain the old data still, rather just add all the data with the year 2020 and month 01 into a CSV file.

what I have now:

```
awk -F, '$3 ~ /2020-01/ {print}' sourceFile.csv > data/2020/01/destonationFile.csv
```

I have tried to play around with grep and `awk`, but do not know how to properly check if the date is correct.
Any advice helps.

sample data as source - sourceData.csv

```
Name,Price,Date,SKU
pixel 5, 20000, 2020-01-04, 124124
iphone 8, 35000,2019-12-11, 124125
note 20 , 50000, 2020-04-16, 124127
note 20 ultra, 60000, 2020-01-12, 124128
s 8, 15000, 2017, 124129
```

Sample data as output - destonationFile.csv

```
pixel 5, 20000, 2020-01-04, 124124
note 20 ultra, 60000, 2020-01-12, 124126
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with _from `2020-01`_ ? Exactly `2020-01`? `2020-01` or newer? Something else?

Comment: Why not using your `awk` script on all input files? Example: `awk -F, '$3 ~ /2020-01/ {print}' sourceFile.csv sourceFile2.csv sourceFile3.csv > data/2020/01/destonationFile.csv`.

Comment: Well done with the formatting and content of your question (after slight edit). Worth of the nod for the effort and following the rules.

Comment: "_add all the data with the year 2020 into a CSV file_" why then do you have the month in the destination path (`data/2020/01/destonationFile.csv`)? Shouldn't it be `data/2020/destonationFile.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts. (1) you were really close and you are thinking along the correct lines. (2) your data file format contains both `','` and `", "` as delimiters in places that will cause problems (e.g. `"35000,2019-12-11"` and `"20000, 2020-01-04"`). (3) To consistently identify `"2020-01..."` at the beginning of the field, you want to *anchor* your REGEX to the beginning with `'^'`. Additionally, `print` is the default action taken by `awk`, so if you have no additional rules to apply, you can simply omit it.

Putting that together and checking for the first record in the file `FNR==1` to also grab the heading for your destination file, you can do:

```bash
awk -F",|, " 'FNR==1 || $3~/^2020-01/' sourceData.csv
```

Where `-F",|, "` allows you to use alternate field-separators to handle the `','` and `", "` separators.

Since you are outputting the entire record that is matching your selection criteria, you can be assured that the records are not modified. So long as the selection is working as you intent, your output file will hold the same content for the records selected from your input file.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `sourceData.csv`, the above would produce:

```
$ awk -F",|, " 'FNR==1 || $3~/^2020-01/' sourceData.csv
Name,Price,Date,SKU
pixel 5, 20000, 2020-01-04, 124124
note 20 ultra, 60000, 2020-01-12, 124128
```

If you don't want the heading in the destination file, simply remove the `"FNR==1 || "` part

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV format is very simple (no commas in fields, no quoted fields) and your 3 input files are `sourceFile.csv`, `sourceFile2.csv` and `sourceFile3.csv`, you can try this minor modification of what you already have:

```bash
$ awk -F, '$3 ~ /^ *2020/ {print}' sourceFile.csv sourceFile2.csv sourceFile3.csv > data/2020/01/destonationFile.csv
```

But if you want to extract all records from year `2020` (not just January `2020`) the output should rather be something like `data/2020/destonationFile.csv`.

Comment: yes, this made it much simpler. Thanks.